# Spring Data Rest adding excerpt projection switches off lazy fetching

Tags: loading, lazy-evaluation, spring-data-rest

I'm new to Spring Data Rest and trying to play around with its basic concepts. Everything works well so far, but few days ago I noticed that the application performance suddenly dropped after putting the projections into business.

These are my entities, repositories and the projection

```
@Entity
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = TABLE)
    private long id;

    private String code;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Category.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Category category;

    //getters & setters
}

@Entity
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = TABLE)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="category", targetEntity=Item.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Item> items;

    //getters & setters
}

@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection=ItemExcerpt.class)
public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, Long>{

}

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface CategoryRepository extends CrudRepository<Category, Long>{

}

@Projection(name="excerpt", types=Item.class)
public interface ItemExcerpt {

    String getName();
}
```

So, all worked fine untill I added the excerpt projection to the ItemRepository `@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection=ItemExcerpt.class)`

Before doing this, when I hit http://localhost:9191/categories Hibernate output was as I expected it to be:

```
select
        category0_.id as id1_0_,
        category0_.name as name2_0_ 
    from
        category category0_
```

This is the output that I get after adding `excerptProjection=ItemExcerpt.class`

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        category0_.id as id1_0_,
        category0_.name as name2_0_ 
    from
        category category0_
Hibernate: 
    select
        items0_.category_id as category4_1_0_,
        items0_.id as id1_1_0_,
        items0_.id as id1_1_1_,
        items0_.category_id as category4_1_1_,
        items0_.code as code2_1_1_,
        items0_.name as name3_1_1_ 
    from
        item items0_ 
    where
        items0_.category_id=?
```

My conclusion is that the excerpt projection makes lazy fetching being ignored on @OneToMany relationship, which leads to a performance drop.
Does anyone know a way to bypass this issue, or is this maybe an expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't exactly that excerpt projections make lazy fetching be ignored.  More specifically, it is that an excerpt projection is telling spring data to include the excerpted data wherever a collection resource would be returned.
From the reference docs [Projections Excerpts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.excerpts), *"An excerpt is a projection that is applied to a resource collection automatically."*.  The unfortunate side-effect of this is that spring-hateoas then ignores that property and instead puts in the hypermedia link to the resource instead.  There is no combination of annotations that i have found that will correct this behavior for you while preserving the output.  @JsonIgnore will not prevent the extra queries.  @RestResource(exported = false) will prevent the queries, but will also prevent the hypermedia link.